# SSRS - exclude hidden values from sum - No SQL To Use ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: reporting-services, sum, hidden-field

hope use can help me with this:

My dataset uses a pre-built module therefore I cannot use SQL adding a row_number() for the field.

I need to be able to exclude hidden values from SUM as follows:

1. In the field I used this expression:
   `IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value), 0, Fields!SpaceArea.Value)`
2. In the Textbox Property for SpaceArea -> Visibility -> show or hide of the field, I also used this expression for hidden:
   `=IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value),True, False)`
3. And the SUM:
   `=Sum(IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value), Fields!SpaceArea.Value, Nothing))`

Then I got this error message:

> previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT 1:**

```
     SpaceID    SpaceArea   RowNumber 
     A          123         1
     A          123         2
     A          123         3
     B          12          1
     B          12          2
     C          1           1
```

**Notes:**

1. SpaceID was grouped as `SpaceID_Group`.
2. The Expected Sum for `SpaceArea = (123 + 12 +1)`.
3. Cannot use `row_number() over (partition by ... )` because there is no SQL. The query was designed with XML, not SQL.

I managed to create another column in the tablix with the row value
 `=RowNumber("SpaceID_Group")`.
But I do not know how to refer it to my Sum. which, if I had SQL , it will look like:
`sum(iif(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!SpaceArea.Value, Nothing))`

Comment: are there any unique columns in your dataset? The only thing that comes to mind for this restricted scenario is possibly a code-behind function that looks up on a unique column value and returns 0 or the value based on the previous logic which you would code in VB

Comment: This seems too easy, but have you just tried summing the value?  You set the value to 0 so it might just work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer.  None of them worked.  Eventhough I set the duplicated values to be 0 , plus hidden.  The sum still  added those values.  and using the Previous aggregate function had error as I mentioned above:  =Sum(IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value), Fields!SpaceArea.Value, Nothing))     THE error is:   
Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

Comment: Even I set the duplicate value to 0 then try as Sum(Fields!SpaceArea.Value)   , it still didn't work.  I will sum everything.

Comment: Wait, if you have already created a new column on your tablix that has the rownumber, why can't you use that IIF statement that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried: inserted a textbox in the tablix and made a rownumber:  
=RowNumber("SpaceID_Group")     
===> got rownumber 1, 2, 3 for the same SpaceID_Group but then I do not know how to refer that rownumber to the Sum.  So I tried:
=sum(iif(ReportItems!Textbox123.Value = 1, Fields!SpaceArea.Value, Nothing))
And here is the error message:
The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox68.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers

Comment: Another try such as  
=sum(iif(RowNumber("SpaceID_Group").Value = 1, Fields!Space_Area.Value, Nothing))
  ==> Error Message:  The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox68.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.

Comment: I understand that I may have to use the code-behind function, but I am not familiar with VB.  All the codes are owned by our vendor.  I am only able to manipulate the report builder.  However this report uses their pre-built model, xml query designer, therefore there is no SQL for me to use "row_number() over (partition by ..."  Do you know if I can add the row_number field in the Dataset -> query designer?

Comment: A screenshot with a sample of the expected output could help

Comment: Hi Again, it looks like my problem description to the issue was edited fine and clear, if you look back up at the top part of my question (EDIT 1), plus my expectation is also there. (Notes)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following custom code to the report (the return value is for debugging)

`Public Shared MyTotal As Integer
Function AddTotal(ByVal t As Integer) As Integer
MyTotal = MyTotal + t
Return Mytotal
End Function`

2. Group on the SpaceId (as you already did) and hide it.
3. Add the expression `Code.AddTotal(Fields!SpaceArea.Value)` to the SpaceId group
4. Add the expression `Code.MyTotal` to field summary.
   In some versions like SSRS 2005, due to execution order you may notice that the calculation returns zero. In this case add a field with the expression bellow the table

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi NIKTRS, I was able to add a textbox in the footer.  I then added this expression in the textbox: =Sum(ReportItems!SpaceArea.value)  and I got the very right result of the SUM, what I expected to see.  However, how do I link that value from the hidden textbox in Page Footer to my report in the main table?

Comment: @Tubi I have changed my approach with custom code which works better.

Comment: I followed your advice.  First of all , since you said the RowId is not working and I do not see its role in here, so I removed the RowId column.  I added the code to the report, and added Code.MyTotal to the sum.  However, it only summed one by one value.  For example , it supposed to sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.  But the first time the result gave 1, when I select previous page, and go back to the last page, the sum = 3 means (1+2),  I did the same: toggle the page and the third time I got the sum = 6 , means (1 + 2 + 3) , and it goes on like that.  Not sure if I did anything wrong here ...

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: By the way, in the report I have many groups, not just one.  And SpaceID is the first group.  Plus, in the report the user does not want to see the duplicated value of SpaceArea, so I had this expression in the textbox / visibility of SpaceArea:  =IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value),True, False).  I am not sure if this has anything to do with the AddTotal Code.

Comment: My report actually looks like this:

Comment: SpaceID    SpaceArea   RowNumber 
     A          123         1
                                2
                                3
     B          12           1
                                2
     C          1            1

Comment: Since the report is not as simple as the sample, the answer depends on the actual report complexity

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008 R2, Report Builder 3.0 is what I am working with.

Comment: I would like to add an image of a better picture of the report.  But I am not sure how to.  I tried what was recommended in the Help below but it would not work.

Comment: Hi Niktrs,  I was finally able to make it work as follows:  =Sum(Max(Fields!SpaceArea.Value, "SpaceIDGroup"))  I would like to thank you so very much for your kindness and your time. :)