# SSRS Sum visible parent row group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I have two row groups. 
and I set the second group to hide unless you click the plus sign of the parent group.

Here is my raw dataset

```
PROJK   ID1523  EMPLOYEE
100     3       JOE001
100     3       KAM002
100     3       MAT102
201     5       JOE001
201     5       MAT122
203     1       KIM222
```

and here is my SSRS matrix. PROJK is the parent group. and notice ID1523 is not summarized like `sum(fields!ID1523.Value)`
[image]

because I don't use SUM(fields!ID1523.Value) in the ID1523 column, essentially when SSRS RUN the report looks like this in IE

```
PROJK   ID1523
+100     3
+201     5
+203     1
```

even when the rows are expanded ID1523 does not repeat the value in the child group because of the way I set it up on the matrix.

How can I Sum ID1523 ? I expect the sum would be 3 + 5 + 1 = 9

Right now if I add total for PROJK Group it will give me 3+3+3+5+5+1 = 20

I am hoping I can solve this via SQL so the raw dataset will look like this

```
PROJK   ID1523  EMPLOYEE
100     3       JOE001
100     0       KAM002
100     0       MAT102
201     5       JOE001
201     0       MAT122
203     1       KIM222
```

Raw data set is a result from two table. with a simple left join on PROJK
Table1 looks like this

```
  PROJK   EMPLOYEE
    100     JOE001
    100     KAM002
    100     MAT102
    201     JOE001
    201     MAT122
    203     KIM222
```

and table2 looks like this

```
PROJK   ID1523  
100     3       
201     5       
203     1
```

Comment: Check a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461128/ssrs-exclude-hidden-values-from-sum-no-sql-to-use-row-number/44561532#44561532

Comment: Thanks. that answer it. I didn't think of partition and row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Partition and Row_number to determine each group in sql

then join only to the first row_number of "table 1"